# How add category programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, category-attribute

How create a category programatically. With the attributes name, url key, image, path, parent id, is active, description.

And

How to insert data for a new attribute added by InstallDate a category. Ejm.: new attribute -> code

Answer (score 5):

Further to Laor's answer, the following code works on Magento 2.1 and uses:

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` for create
`\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` for saving

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require '/www/mag2.local/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

### Setting area code
### NOTE: more info http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('base');

createCategory();

function createCategory() {
        global $objectManager;

        $category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create();

        $category->setName('Computer 3');
        $category->setParentId(1); // 1: root category.
        $category->setIsActive(true);
        $category->setCustomAttributes([
                'description' => 'Computer 3 desc',
        ]);

        $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use code like this:

```
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category', ['data' =>[
    "id" => 5,
    "parent_id" => 2,
    "name" => "cat2",
    "is_active" => true,
    "position" => 2,
    "include_in_menu" => false,
]);

$category->setCustomAttributes([
    "display_mode"=> "PRODUCTS",
    "is_anchor"=> "1",
    "custom_use_parent_settings"=> "0",
    "custom_apply_to_products"=> "0",
    "url_key"=> "cat2",
    "url_path"=> "cat2",
    "automatic_sorting"=> "0",
    'new_attribute' => 'value' // <-- your attribute
]);

$repository = $objectManager->get(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
$repository->save($category);
```

Comment: i have updated the code @Kandy... use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;   ..... $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
  $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $areaCode=$url->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
  $state=$areaCode->setAreaCode('frontend');
  
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  for set area code and object manager...but i get bootstrap error Call to a member function sendResponse() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_6\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php on line 259

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for creating category programmatically too, Kandy answer looks good but I would have used interface instead of objectmanager :

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` for create

`\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` for saving

Moreover you need to remove 'id' or it results in a NoSuchEntityException because of the check at save : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php#L117-L119

Answer (score 0):

Please check given below URL to get your issue resolve.

URL: [magento 2 create categories programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134911/magento-2-create-categories-programmatically)