# magento 2 create categories programmatically

Tags: magento2, category, programmatically

I would like to create categories programmatically in **magento 2**.

Please suggest me proper code for it.

I have try this code [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105284/how-add-category-programmatically-magento-2) but not working properly . I have to create number of categories on one code with sub-categoties. like import export.

Comment: check this it will help you : http://www.onlinecode.org/magento-create-category-programmatically/

Comment: @DhavalDave link you gave for M1

Comment: @Ansyori May :: my mistake, http://www.onlinecode.org/create-category-programmatically-magento-2/ its for m2 check it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
/// Get Website ID
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
echo 'websiteId: '.$websiteId." ";

/// Get Store ID
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
echo 'storeId: '.$storeId." ";

/// Get Root Category ID
$rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
echo 'rootNodeId: '.$rootNodeId." ";
/// Get Root Category
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootNodeId);

$categorys=array('Levis','Wranglers','Basics'); // Category Names
foreach($categorys as $cat)
{

$name=ucfirst($cat);
$url=strtolower($cat);
$cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
$categoryFactory=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
/// Add a new sub category under root category
$categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();
$categoryTmp->setName($name);
$categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
$categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
$categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
$categoryTmp->setParentId($rootCat->getId());
$mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
$categoryTmp->setImage('/m2.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/m2.png
$categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
$categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
$categoryTmp->save();
}
```

This will add add multiple category programmatically below to the root category of magento2

set category path and do the reindex and flush cache

For reference you can chk.

http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-add-category-programmatically/

https://vinothkumaarr.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/add-multiple-category-programmatically-magento2/

Comment: this ->save() method is deprecated, I think the way to go is to use repository instead.

Comment: This worked only half for me. I needed to save the category so I can get the ID, and then set the "path" on the category using the new ID, then save again. In my case the "path" had an invalid value and was not visible in the category tree in Magento Admin. Setting the path by hand in a 2nd step worked fine.