# create categories and sub categories programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, category

How to create categories and sub categories programmatically in magento2?

Please anyone knows then explain me.

Comment: check link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134916

Comment: Have you got any solution for create tree level categories. I am facing same issue. Let me know if you have got solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use following code to create category and subcategory. just make slight changes as per your requirement and use it where you want to create categories and sub categories

```
$objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//you should prefer to use dependency injection here
$cats = [
    "cat1","cat2"
];

$parent_id = 322; // category id of parent
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $data = [
        'data' => [
            "parent_id" => $parent_id,
            'name' => $cat,
            "is_active" => true,
            "position" => 10,
            "include_in_menu" => false,
        ]

     ];
    $category = $objectManager ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category', $data);
    $repository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
    $result = $repository->save($category);
}
```

credits: http://www.zexperto.com/magento2x/create-category-magento2-programmatically

Comment: I tried this code but it's not  working......pg not working error was displayed.wt i can do this

Comment: what error you got.. ?? share how you implemented this code

Comment: I have created a php script in magento2 root directory and executed the file but its not working.

Comment: i will suggest you to create a new module and put the code in controller or add the code in some existing controller of some module that you have created

Comment: @magentonoob I have tried this code it's working fine for root level categories. But can't able to create tree level categories.

Comment: @KirtiNariya  i could not get you. Can you please share what you are trying to do and show your code please

Comment: @magentonoob That above issue solved as i did stuck.

 But  i have one more question.
I have import categories vis csv. I tried to save categories pragmatically and categories save properly but after reimport csv means while updating categories not saved categories.

Comment: can you please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can create the category and subcategory in the following way.

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('base');

createCategory();

function createCategory() {
        global $objectManager;

        $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category', ['data' =>[
    "id" => 5,
    "parent_id" => 2,
    "name" => "cat2",
    "is_active" => true,
    "position" => 2,
    "include_in_menu" => false,
]);

$category->setCustomAttributes([
    "display_mode"=> "PRODUCTS",
    "is_anchor"=> "1",
    "custom_use_parent_settings"=> "0",
    "custom_apply_to_products"=> "0",
    "url_key"=> "cat2",
    "url_path"=> "cat2",
    "automatic_sorting"=> "0",
    'new_attribute' => 'value' // <-- your attribute
]);

$repository = $objectManager->get(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
$repository->save($category);
}
```