# Import category programmaically in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to import a category programmatically in magento2 using CSV file, CSV contains only one column like `Category Name >> Women, Men`
So How to create it ? 
Please explain me if anybody knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Visit here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134916/48571

Comment: But i want import category name through csv file only....

Comment: Yes but if you have only one column than you can copy the names in array and create categories using above link.

Comment: Actually i'm run this code but  created categories not visible in abmin panel

Comment: I have tested it. It's working perfectly. Please check your store id and website id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67050/discussion-between-dinesh-yadav-and-mahalakshmi-m).

Comment: @ManoM Have you done with csv import categories? I have same issue i am working in csv import categories. Let me know if you have got solution.