# Assign category programatically to products in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, category-products

I want to assign promo category to products which have special price. Should I create a custom module or create a php file in root directory?

I found this solution: [How add category programmatically magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105284/how-add-category-programmatically-magento-2)

Does it still possible in Magento 2.3.4?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it is possible.
> You can assign promo category to products which have special price programatically.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?